# How is the Ethereum Name Service Avatar records used?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, ens

[image: Screen of the ENS TEXT Record with the avatar field]

What is the use or how is the avatar field in the ENS TEXT RECORD used?.

I am assuming that when the ENS address represents  a Token's contract address, the Image avatar pops up with token when it is searched for in exchanges or maybe added to wallets by first searching for the token using the ENS address like in the example below:
[image: example]

Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Also would like to understand how this field work

Answer (score 0):

Here is some documentation. https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-634#global-keys

This feature is likely used by services like Zerion or Zapper to display an avatar like they do with the ens name it's self. So I assume you point it at some resource to be displayed as a profile picture. Idk if you can point it at an NFT but probably.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not used for the token logo as far as I know. It's just a metadata field and can be used by any Dapp, as a profile picture for example.